# Изменения CSS файла для мобильного устройства

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

Есть сайт с ручным переключением стилей с Десктопа/Мобильный.

```
<select onchange="set_style(this)">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Обычная‹</option>
        <option value="none">Мобильная</option>
    </select>
```

Подскажите скрипт, который бы автоматически определял что пользователь зашел с телефона и автоматически ставил бы ему мобильную тему.

Для определения мобильного устройства, есть такое решение

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DetectTheThing()
    {
       var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
       if (uagent.search("iphone") > -1 || uagent.search("ipad") > -1 
       || uagent.search("android") > -1 || uagent.search("blackberry") > -1
       || uagent.search("webos") > -1)
          window.location.href ="otherindex.html";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать такую запись

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    // мобильное устройство
  } else {
    // десктоп
  }
```

или вот скрип, [mobile-detect](https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js). Белее громоздкий, но настраивается тоньше